# Como definir várias variáveis de uma vez dentro de uma trigger no SQLServer

Tags: sql-server

Olá, estou criando uma TRIGGER onde devo fazer uma série de tratamentos após um UPDATE em uma tabela no SQLServer. Nessa TRIGGER, eu preciso definir algumas variáveis para que eu possa trabalhar com elas no resto do script, assim:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    nome NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    telefone NVARCHAR(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    email NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
);

GO

CREATE TRIGGER [TR_foo_onUpdate] ON foo AFTER UPDATE AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @id BIT = (SELECT id FROM inserted),
            @nome NVARCHAR(100) = (SELECT nome FROM inserted),
            @telefone NVARCHAR(30) = (SELECT telefone FROM inserted),
            @email NVARCHAR(100) = (SELECT email FROM inserted);

    /* continuação do script aqui... */

END
```

minha questão é o seguinte, existe alguma forma de eu fazer o declare sem ter que fazer 4 `SELECT`'s? A pergunta é mais para otimização pois com certeza pode ser usada em inúmeros outros scripts...

Comment: Sugestão de leitura: "Armadilhas na programação de procedimentos de gatilho" -> 
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/pt-br/contents/articles/38010.armadilhas-na-programacao-de-procedimentos-de-gatilho.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @id BIT,
        @nome NVARCHAR(100),
        @telefone NVARCHAR(30),
        @email NVARCHAR(100);


SELECT @id = id,
       @nome = nome,
       @telefone = telefone,
       @email = email
  FROM inserted
```

Comment: Lol... sinceramente não achei que era tão simples como isso...